# About the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{5},\sqrt{2+\operatorname{i}}]/\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{5}]$

Tags: galois-theory

Some notations: let $K=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{5}]$, $N=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{5},\sqrt{2+\operatorname{i}}]$, $a=\sqrt{2+i}$, $b=-a$, $c=\sqrt{2-i}$, $d=-c$.

I know that $N/K$ is normal because it decompose the biquadratic $P=X^4-4X^2+5$: we have in fact $N=\mathbb{Q}[a, b, c, d]$ because $ac=\sqrt{5}$.

I know that $N/K$ has degre 4 because the minimal polynomial of $a$ stay $P$ because $a^2\notin K$ and $a, b$ and $c$ are not in $K$.

I know that $\operatorname{Gal}(N/K)$ is Klein's Viergruppe $V\simeq\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ because of the degree $[N:K]$ and the relations $b=-a$, $d=-c$ and $ac=\sqrt{5}$.

We have three subgroups $H_i$ respectively generated by (with the stand embedding of the Galois group in $S_4$) $(ab)(cd)$, $(ac)(bd)$ and $(ad)(bc)$.

The corresponding fixed subfield are $K[a+c]$ for $H_2$, $K[a+d]$ for $H_3$.

So my problem is what is the fixed subifeld corresponding to $H_1$. It should be $K[a+b]$ but $a+b=0$. I can't have $\operatorname{Inv}(H_1)=\operatorname{Inv}(\operatorname{Gal}(N/K))=K$ otherwise I should have $\operatorname{Gal}(N/K)=H_1$.

Comment: Aren't $L$ and $N$ suppposed to be the same field?

Comment: Yes I edit this.

Answer (score 1):

We can be a bit more explicit with the description of the fields you already gave (this may turn out to be useful later on). Let $\alpha=\arctan\dfrac12$ be the argument of $a$. Then $\cos\alpha=2/\sqrt5$ and as $|a|=\root4\of5$, the real part of $a$ is
$$\Re a=(a+c)/2=\root4\of5\cos\frac\alpha2=\root4\of5\sqrt{\frac{2+\sqrt5}{2\sqrt5}}=\sqrt{\frac{2+\sqrt5}{2}},$$
where I used the trig formula
$$
\cos\frac\alpha2=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\alpha}2}.
$$
So we see that $\operatorname{Inv}(H_2)$ is a quartic real field. This is hardly a surprise given that the permutation $(ac)(bd)$ is the restriction of the usual complex conjugation to $N$.

A similar calculation shows that
$$
\frac{a+d}2=\frac{a-c}2=i\root4\of5\sin\frac\alpha2=i\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt5-2}2},
$$
and this generates the field $\operatorname{Inv}(H_3)$.

---

You specifically asked about $\operatorname{Inv}(H_1)$. I start with a hint: The product $ab$ is also invariant under $(ab)(cd)$.